# Regex negative lookaround with optional whitespace

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to find the digits, not succeeded by certain words. I do this using regular expressions in Python3. My guess is that negative lookarounds have to be used, but I'm struggling due to optional whitespaces. See the following example:

`'200 word1 some 50 foo and 5foo 30word2'`

Note that in reality word1 and word2 can be replaced by a lot of different words, making it much harder to search for a positive match on these words. Therefore it would be easier to exclude the numbers succeeded by `foo`. The expected result is:

`[200, 30]`

My try:

```
s = '200 foo some 50 bar and 5bar 30foo
pattern = r"[0-9]+\s?(?!foo)"
re.findall(pattern, s)
```

Results in

`['200', '50 ', '5', '3']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = '200 word1 some 50 foo and 5foo 30word2'
pattern = r"\b[0-9]+(?!\s*foo|[0-9])"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
# => ['200', '30']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/w364pk) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb%5B0-9%5D%2B(%3F!%5Cs*foo%7C%5B0-9%5D)):

[image]

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ ASCII digits only
- `(?!\s*foo|[0-9])` - not immediately followed with

  - `\s*foo` - 0+ whitespaces and `foo` string
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9]` - an ASCII digit.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the pattern `\b[0-9]+(?!\s*foo\b)(?=\D)`, which says to find all number which are not followed by optional whitespace and the word `foo`.

```
s = '200 word1 some 50 foo and 5foo 30word2'
matches = re.findall(r'\b[0-9]+(?!\s*foo\b)(?=\D)', s)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['200', '30']
```